# Conjugating the Mobius Transformation $\mathcal M(z)=1/(z-2i)$

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation, riemann-sphere

Consider the Mobius transformation $\mathcal M:\textbf C^*\to\textbf C^*$ (where $\textbf C^*:=\textbf C\cup\{\infty\}$ denotes the extended complex plane/Riemann sphere) defined by:
$$\mathcal M(z):=\frac{1}{z-2i}$$
I'm pretty sure this particular Mobius transformation $\mathcal M$ has only one fixed point in $\textbf C^*$, namely at $\mathcal M(i)=i$. And I'm also pretty sure that the *collection* of all Mobius transformations with *exactly one fixed point* is equal to the *conjugacy class* of the simple rightward unit Mobius *translation* $\mathcal T(z):=z+1$ (which has one fixed point at $z=\infty$) in the Mobius group. Therefore, I thought it should be possible to conjugate $\mathcal M$ by some *intermediary* Mobius transformation $\mathcal I(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ such that:
$$\mathcal T=\mathcal I\circ\mathcal M\circ\mathcal I^{-1}$$
However, I seem to be unable to find an intermediary Mobius transformation $\mathcal I(z)$ that successfully accomplishes this conjugation. Any ideas why?

Comment: We have $\mathcal{T}\circ\mathcal{I}=\mathcal{I}\circ\mathcal{M}$ and $I(i)=\infty $ as fixed point of $\mathcal{T}.$ Doesn't that imply $ci+d=0$ and thus $c=d=0$ which makes $I$ not invertible?

Comment: $1/(i z +1)$ conjugates your transformation to $z+1$;  $\{a, b, c, d\}$ and $\{ ta, tb, tc, td\}$, $t\neq 0$, define the same transformation.